# Xcode 9.2: how to get a project from a remote git repository?

Tags: xcode, gitlab, xcode9.2

Trying to create a project in XCode 9.2 from a remote git repository on gitlab (not github). I searched the Internet and found how to add (any) remote git repository in XCode, but apparently there was a change in XCode 9.2 and in the menu they only let you add github repositories.
Any ideas?